# Acer Aspire Desktop switch from Vista to Windows 7 scenario

Tags: windows-7, upgrade

I'm currently looking at installing Windows 7 on my Acer Aspire.

My main worry/question is about the builtin e-recovery functionality.

I would prefer to do a clean install rather than an upgrade, but the downside of this is that I will no longer have the e-recovery functionality, which allows me to backup and restore the system disk.

As I see it, I have a few options, I'd quite like to know if anyone out there has experience with any of these, and if there is any handy advice on things I should avoid...

1) Do an upgrade, so I preserve e-recovery, and also all the accumulated cruft of Vista

2) Clean install, then download e-recovery from the Acer website, hoping that it is still up to date, and that it will work with Windows 7.

3) Clean install, junk e-recovery and buy another ghosting application - possibly keeping the hidden partition for just that.

I guess if I have the Windows7 install disks (not the case for Vista), I don't have to worry so much about being able to reinstall...

I'm also going to try and get some answer out of Acer support on this, though I don't hold much hope...

Answer (score 1):

The accumulated cruft isn't so bad. The upgrade process is very clean compared to previous upgrades.

Ping Acer to see if they have a Windows 7 recovery disc, or do a fresh install and come up with an alternative recovery plan (the built-in Windows backup is not bad at all on this version).

Comment: Hm, I've got lots of accumulated junk in AppData, temp stuff too. The ideal for me is to take advantage of the install to get rid of all that stuff, then ghost the clean install and be able to restore it every so often to lose the 'cruft'. I take your point that upgrade in itself might not be too bad.

Comment: Correct. The Windows Backup software generates an image for you if you want, which I would suggest. Also, SysInternals has a new tool that writes your disk to a VHD file.

Answer (score 0):

I`ve upgraded my acer aspire to windows 7 and the e-recvery has changed.It now does a data security function it didn`t do before on the empowering technology and the e-recovery has dissapeared altogether.
                          Peter.

Comment: Yeah, well that's the windows7 data security function, I think. I believe it creates a hidden partition too. It would be interesting to see if it uses the same one, or if it creates another one - in which case you just lost another 10Gb...